# Enable multilanguage in ng-grid header name

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have tried `$translate` service as follows:

```
 columnDefs: [{ 
                field: 'option_name',
                displayName: $translate('Optionname'),
                cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"  ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)" ></div>' 
            },
            ...
```

it is showing `{}`. I also tried translate via filter:

```
columnDefs: [{ 
                field: 'option_name',
                displayName: '{{ Optionname | translate }}',
                cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"  ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)" ></div>' 
            },
            ...
```

but it is showing `{{ Optionname | translate }}` so how can i translate header name in `ng-grid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interact with `$translation` scope directly by using `$translate.instant('id')`. So `.instant()` will return a `string` which is the translated one. You can read about this scope in the [documentation](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate).

#### Example

```
columnDefs: [
    {   field: 'option_name',
        displayName: $translate.instant('Optionname'),
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"  ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)" ></div>'
    },
    ...
```

#### Reinit `ng-grid` on language change to for translation of `displayName` again.

```
$translate.use("en_US").then(function(data){ 
    $scope.columnDefs = columnDefs: [{   
        field: 'option_name',
        displayName: $translate.instant('Optionname'),
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"  ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)" ></div>'
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Once a language is changed, you need to update `displayName`  on you own. Just reinitialize the `ng-grid` with the same data, so `$translate.instant('Optionname')` will be executed again.

Comment: how can i achieve this ?  it is good if you can provide some example

Comment: Urgs, your removed the "right answer tick"? ... mhm. `$translate.use("en_US").then(function(data){ $scope.columnDefs = [...] });` Please ask a new question ...